# Determine whether WebSocket was closed by browser or server

Tags: browser, websocket

Is there a way to reliably determine from the `onClose` event of a websocket in a browser, whether it was closed "by us" (the browser) or "by them" (the server)?

I'm aware of the close codes, but in my case it's possible that the server and client send the same close code, so that's no way to discern the two cases.

Comment: Unless there's a telling close code that was specifically set to discern the difference, I don't think you can tell which end initiated the close.

Comment: That's the question. Other implementations of Websockets (e.g. java-websockets) provide such a flag in the close event.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [webSocket specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-42) that indicates who initiated the close.